# Count selected elements for each line and create an arrayformula that groups by number of counts

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

We have asked users:

```
What to do with the money?
[ ] paint the bridge
[ ] rebuild the school
[ ] keep the money
[ ] Other : [____________________]
```

Here is the spreadsheet with their answers:

```
     A          B
1    Name       Choices
2    Lilia      paint the bridge, rebuild the school, keep the money
3    Paul       rebuild the school, paint the bridge, do something else
4    Margerite  keep the money, I don't know, do what you want
5    John       paint the bridge
...
800
```

I want a formula that output the number of official choices (excluding *other*) picked per user.

With the first 4 rows of data, the formula would output this table:

```
D                           E
Nbr of choices a user made  Frequency (Nbr of users who made these choices)
0                           0
1                           2
2                           1
3                           1
```

Couldn't find a way to get this right from a single formula. For a starter, I wanted to split each line (of B2: B) by "," but couldn't find a way to apply a fn (split) to each line in an formula...

Even with 800 rows of data (`B2:B`), the resulting table (`D2:E5`) would always be 4 rows long plus titles (and two column wide)

I could do this in C2, and replicate manually with the "+" corner icon...

```
=countif(B2;"*rebuild the school*")+countif(B2;"*keep the money*")+countif(B2;"*paint the bridge*")
```

And then do in E2:

```
=arrayformula(countif(C2:C;D2:D5))
```

But I'd like to generate the table of frequencies in one formula, without any manual action (without `C` column).

So I am looking for a way to "map" the first function to each row, put this in the second fn.

**ANSWER by Akshin Jalilov EXPLAINED**

This is the answer by Akshin Jalilov, but shorter (and with international notations)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="";;COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA
(IFERROR(IF(FIND("paint the bridge";B2:B);Row(B2:B);0)));"="&row(B2:B))
+COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND(
"rebuild the school";B2:B);Row(B2:B);0)));"="&row(B2:B))
+COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND(
"keep the money";B2:B);Row(B2:B);0)));"="&row(B2:B))));"="&D2:D5))
```

*Step1:*

`IF(FIND("rebuild the school";B2:B);Row(B2:B);0)`

This means, for each row (`B2:B`) find "rebuild the school". If you find it, **return the number of the row**, otherwise, return 0.

*Step2:*

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(Step1))`

Wrap this in an ARRAYFORMULA so that you return the results for each row.
I think IFERROR is there to prevent an error from stopping the process.

*Step3:*

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="";;COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("paint the bridge";B2:B);Row(B2:B);0)));"="&row(B2:B))+countif(Step2)+countif(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("keep the money";B2:B);Row(B2:B);0)));"="&row(B2:B))))
```

This will count valid votes made by each users. This is equivalent to C2 formula referred in my manual process. But is it now part of a single global formula.

*Step4:*
Lastly, the rest of the formula counts frequencies of each voting count possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this formula is large but this is the closest I got to what you want. 
Now to make it easy, name your responses range "Responses". I assume it is **B2:B**.

Here is the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Countif(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Responses="",,COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(row(Responses),({ARRAYFORMULA(Row(Responses)),ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("paint the bridge",Responses),Row(Responses),0))),ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("rebuild the school",Responses),Row(Responses),0))),ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("keep the money",Responses),Row(Responses),0)))}),2),"="&row(Responses))+COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(row(Responses),({ARRAYFORMULA(Row(Responses)),ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("paint the bridge",Responses),Row(Responses),0))),ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("rebuild the school",Responses),Row(Responses),0))),ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("keep the money",Responses),Row(Responses),0)))}),3),"="&row(Responses))+COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(row(Responses),({ARRAYFORMULA(Row(Responses)),ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("paint the bridge",Responses),Row(Responses),0))),ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("rebuild the school",Responses),Row(Responses),0))),ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(FIND("keep the money",Responses),Row(Responses),0)))}),4),"="&row(Responses)))),"="&D2:D5))
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ry1NlqTYf86Q5IX9tXPxvH3k2sOEattowKmZXVx1Rd8/edit?usp=sharing) is an example if how it works. I am not sure which one exactly you wanted so added both

Comment: Are your responses in column b2:b?

Comment: Yes, they are. Also, even if my data has say 800 rows, the output should be a table of 4 rows (four possibilities) plus titles, and two columns...

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to understand, but I think I got what you wanted. Check the edited formula and the example sheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I've found a shorter way based on your answer, see my second update.

Comment: Yeah I tried to do it all in one formula without using Column **C**. Also I assigned "Responses" through Data->Named Ranges.

Comment: The shorter version of your formula doesn't use C column neither. Thanks for the Named Ranges tip :-)